# error: could not find `solana-cargo-build-sbf` in registry `crates-io` with version `=1.19.0`

Tags: rust, solana, anchor-solana, rustup

im build a project using anchor and wheen i use `anchor build` it gives error

```
package `solana-program v1.18.8` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.75.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.72.0-dev
Either upgrade to rustc 1.75.0 or newer, or use
cargo update -p solana-program@1.18.8 --precise ver
where `ver` is the latest version of `solana-program` supporting rustc 1.72.0-dev
```

but the rustc v is 1.77.0
and solana-cli 1.18.1
and i don't know why and when i use `cargo-build-sbf --version`
it shows

```
solana-cargo-build-sbf 1.18.1
platform-tools v1.39
rustc 1.72.0
```

i have also updated `rustup toolchain`
but again can't be done
can anyone please help me

and when i try to install `cargo install solana-cargo-build-sbf --force`
but it gives

```
Updating crates.io index
error: could not find `solana-cargo-build-sbf` in registry `crates-io` with version `=1.19.0
```

Comment: Please double check that `rustup show` agrees with you on what toolchain is used here as the `cargo-build-sbf --version` output you provided _does_ pin your rustc to 1.72 (perhaps something is shipping a [toolchain override file](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html#the-toolchain-file)?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same issue today, it worked fine 2/3 days ago.

Downgrading to an older version did the trick I was able to build and deploy on devnet:

```
cargo update -p solana-program@1.18.8 --precise 1.18.1
```